# Invalid cross-device linked. Multiple shares from the same NAS

Tags: ubuntu, hard-link

I have a NAS devices, and I've mounted 2 shared folders from this one device.

> QNAP
>
> Ubuntu 18.04

fstab config:

```
//192.168.0.10/Media /media/QNAP_Media cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0 0 0
//192.168.0.10/Rdownload /media/QNAP_Rdownload cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0 0 0
```

`mount | column -t`

```
//192.168.0.10/Media                                on  /media/QNAP_Media                      type  cifs             (rw,relatime,vers=3.0,cache=strict,username=admin,domain=,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.0.10,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
//192.168.0.10/Rdownload                            on  /media/QNAP_Rdownload                  type  cifs             (rw,relatime,vers=3.0,cache=strict,username=admin,domain=,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.0.10,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

When I try to hard-link from one share to another, I get the `invalid cross-device link` error.

As far as I can tell, these shares exist on the same partition, which is what one user suggested.

Any ideas why else I may not be able to create hard-links from one share to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot hardlink between different underlying devices. See if softlinks work.

Comment: What do you mean by underlying devices? Are these not the same device? Softlinks will not serve my purpose ...

Comment: hardlinks are links within a filesystem. If they are mounted on different points they can't be hardlinked.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I was under the impression that they were the same file system because it's the same physical box. I was unaware that different mount points means different file systems.